# How to notify list activity that one of its items has been updated in detail activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, master-detail

Imagine we want to design G+ application. It has a list activity/fragment and by click on an item then detail activity/fragment will be displayed.

My problem is, I don't understand if user hits plus button in detail activity and click on back button then how its counterpart item in list knows that user has clicked it in detail screen (since it shows number of plus oned as same as detail activity)?

Comment: I guess, Same data is used by List fragment and Detail fragment. When you comeback from Detail fragment to list fragment, notifyDataSetChanged() may update the list fragment incase of any updates in Detail fragment.

Comment: List items come from database. Therefore, by click on +1 button in detail fragment then database will be updated while copy of items are in memory in list fragment.

Comment: Right. By calling ListView adapter's notifyDataSetChanged(), incase of change in Detail fragment, ListView will refresh its contents from DB through its adapter. Isn't it ?

Comment: It's not, because based on architecture, list fragment asks database to pass a page of Post items to it. Then fragment will pass the list to adapter. Since, list is in memory then doesn't notify when user get back from detail screen.

Comment: Guess you need to explore Content providers and content observers to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's bit late, thought of sharing my answer as it might help others who are coming across similar situation. Basically, you need to create an interface in the detail fragment class and implement it in the parent activity and use it to update the master list through notifyDataSetChanged().

You might want to refer to following SOF thread as an implmentation reference - [Update ListView in Master/Detail after a form is saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647517/update-listview-in-master-detail-after-a-form-is-saved)